# Tikz: four nodes above a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

There are commands: left, right and above. I can get three nodes above a node by them but without creating empty nodes, I cannot think other way. So how can I get four nodes above a node in Tikz?

**Example where consider a graph with five nodes where four nodes above just one node: how to do that? More position commands?**

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {};
\node [above right=of A] (B) {}; 
\node [above left=of A] (C) {}; 
\node [above =of A] (D) {};
%How to have a fourth node above A that is not on top of B,C or D?
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Seems you can consider a matrix of nodes?

Comment: @OlgaK what is matrix of nodes? I am creating a lattice like [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4WsXD.png) where the root is connected to four nodes above it. Because each graph is a subgraph to the root and not each other, lattice where a root superceded by many nodes (not just by two).

Comment: Is this a picture you want?

Comment: @OlgaK no, it was an example about a lattice where order by the subgraph inclusion. Now the question can be related to lattice like that but with four nodes: not just 2 or 3 above one node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to use polar coordinates to place nodes at arbitrary positions:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A};
%How to have a fourth node above A that is not on top of B,C or D?
\node at (A) [shift=(36 :1cm)] (B) {B}; 
\node at (A) [shift=(72 :1cm)] (C) {C}; 
\node at (A) [shift=(108:1cm)] (D) {D};
\node at (A) [shift=(144:1cm)] (E) {E};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use `above` with different `xshift`s:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) {A};
\node [above=of A, xshift= 1.5cm] (B) {B}; 
\node [above=of A, xshift=  .5cm] (C) {C}; 
\node [above=of A, xshift= -.5cm] (D) {D};
\node [above=of A, xshift=-1.5cm] (E) {E};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: So instead of left/above/right commands, it is best to use polar coordinates for arbitrary number of nodes? Good choice +1!